# Error in import package of MS flow

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework

When I'm import the package of MS flow in other site I'm facing this problem..[image]

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? What steps you followed? What is the error message?

Comment: can you tell which type of information I can share with you in the red box im facing this issue if im import the same package with another site it is working without any error

Comment: Image was not attached to your question when I added above comments. Check if user account you are using to import flow has permissions to the SharePoint site. If not, grant the necessary permissions and try again once.